# How to use serialized data in asp.net mvc and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, serialization

I am using jQuery UI sortable to sort a list in the DOM. I succesfully have an ajax functionposting this string to my mvc action:

```
list[]=2&list[]=3&list[]=28&list[]=1
```

I'm trying to figure out how to get this serialized list of numbers into a `List<int>` so I can actually access them from C#.

How would I do this? I've already tried this method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string RoleTierUpdate( string[] form)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var item in form)
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("id: {0}<br />", item);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

I was thinking I could convert the array of string into a list of integers. But this returned the following output:

```
    id: 2
    id: ,
    id: 3
    id: ,
    id: 2
    id: 8
    id: ,
    id: 1
```

Is ther an easier way of getting this data into a list of int?

### Edit

Here's the code that executes the ajax post:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Sortable
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#sortThis").sortable({
            handle: '.handle',
            update: function () {

                // get new order
                var order = $('#sortThis').sortable('serialize');

                // excecute ajax for db update
                $.post(
                    "/find/AdminMember/RoleTierUpdate/",
                    order,
                    function (data) {
                        $("#info").html(data);
                    }
                );

                $("#info2").html(">>" + order + "<<");
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

`order` contains the string I showed above.

### Edit 2

Updated controller to:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string RoleTierUpdate( List<int> list, MemberData md) // change to List<int> list
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        if (list != null) // added check for null
        {
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                sb.AppendFormat("id: {0}<br />", item);
            }
        }
        else {
            sb.Append("form is null");
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Updated ajax to:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true; // added

        $("#sortThis").sortable({
            handle: '.handle',
            update: function () {

                // get new order
                var order = $('#sortThis').sortable('serialize');

                // excecute ajax for db update
                $.post(
                    "/find/AdminMember/RoleTierUpdate/",
                    order,
                    function (data) {
                        $("#info").html(data);
                    }
                );

                $("#info2").html(">>" + order + "<<");
            }
        });

    });
```

The output from this is:

```
form is null
```

Comment: Did you try using `public string RoleTierUpdate( List<int> form)`

Comment: @Mahesh - Yes, I did try that as well. When I do that `form` is `null`. I suspect it's because that serialized string uses `list[]` as the collection key. I tried doing somthing like `List<int> list` but that returns `null` as well. And, `List<int> list[]` is not a valid statement.

So, I suspect that I'm not able to use mvc's modelbinder to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the reason MVC's modelbinder wasn't willing to bind the string

```
list[]=2&list[]=3&list[]=28&list[]=1
```

to a `List<int> list` is because of the "[]" in the keys. I added this javascript to my jQuery:

```
// get new order
 var order = $('#sortThis').sortable('serialize');
 order = order.replace(/\[\]/gi, "")
```

Once I took out the "[]" from the keys everything was great. The action returned this result:

```
id: 2
id: 3
id: 28
id: 1
```

Which is exactly what I needed. The modelbinding to `List<int>` is working great.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET will automatically detect that you're trying to use a list. Do this:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult RoleTierUpdate(List<String> list)
```

or swap out `String` for `Int32` if you are expecting integers.

Comment: Of course you are able to. Are you using jquery by any chance to send the data back to the server?

Comment: It's possible you may need to change some settings. At the top of your javascript file, add this line: `jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;` and try again. If this doesn't work, try stepping through your debugger to find out what exactly you're getting from the server.

Comment: @quakkels, put that line on the top of your file, outside of any functions or anything. should just be the first line of your js file.

Comment: As long as that line executes before the actual ajax does... I really doubt that it matters where it is.